# Qt+OpenCV on Ubuntu won't run/debug: Failed to start application

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ubuntu, qt-creator

Im trying to run/debug a simple sample of OpenCV with Qt Creator without success

**ENVIRONMENT**

Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit)

Qt Creator 3.0.0 Based on Qt 5.2.0 (64 bit)

OpenCV 2.4.8

**SOURCE**

main.cpp

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void help() {
    cout <<"\nDemonstrate Canny edge detection\n"<< endl;
}

int edgeThresh = 1;
Mat image, gray, edge, cedge;

// define a trackbar callback
void onTrackbar(int, void*) {
    blur(gray, edge, Size(3,3));
    // Run the edge detector on grayscale
    Canny(edge, edge, edgeThresh, edgeThresh*3, 3);
    cedge = Scalar::all(0);
    image.copyTo(cedge, edge);
    imshow("Edge map", cedge);
}

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    //QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    char* filename = argc == 2 ? argv[1] : (char*)"fruits.jpg";
    image = imread(filename, 1);
    if(image.empty()) {
        //help();
        return -1;
    }
    help();
    cedge.create(image.size(), image.type());
    cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    // Create a window
    namedWindow("Edge map", 1);
    // create a toolbar
    createTrackbar("Canny threshold", "Edge map", &edgeThresh, 100, onTrackbar);
    // Show the image
    onTrackbar(0, 0);
    // Wait for a key stroke; the same function arranges events processing
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
    //return a.exec();
}
```

FirstQtProject.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-01-13T22:34:52
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = FirstQtProject
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/local/include/opencv2"

LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

**BUILD INFORMATION**

```
20:45:14: Running steps for project FirstQtProject...
20:45:14: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
20:45:14: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../FirstQtProject -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -I../../Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/include -I../../Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I. -o main.o ../FirstQtProject/main.cpp
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/home/f/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64 -Wl,-rpath,/home/f/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib -o FirstQtProject main.o   `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -L/home/f/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Core -lpthread 
{ test -n "" && DESTDIR="" || DESTDIR=.; } && test $(gdb --version | sed -e 's,[^0-9][^0-9]*\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\).*,\1\2,;q') -gt 72 && gdb --nx --batch --quiet -ex 'set confirm off' -ex "save gdb-index $DESTDIR" -ex quit 'FirstQtProject' && test -f FirstQtProject.gdb-index && objcopy --add-section '.gdb_index=FirstQtProject.gdb-index' --set-section-flags '.gdb_index=readonly' 'FirstQtProject' 'FirstQtProject' && rm -f FirstQtProject.gdb-index || true
20:45:16: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
20:45:16: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

**ERRORS**

Run the project without "Run in terminal" unchecked

```
Starting /home/f/workspace/build-FirstQtProject-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/FirstQtProject...

Demonstrate Canny edge detection

The program has unexpectedly finished.
/home/f/workspace/build-FirstQtProject-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/FirstQtProject crashed
```

Run the project without "Run in terminal" checked

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAegn.jpg

Debug

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJu4x.jpg

Comment: do this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/244336/receiving-error-while-trying-to-debug-in-qtproject to enable debugging in QtCreator and than debug and paste more info (mainly where does it crash)

Comment: Thank you for your response prajmus. With your help i can enable the debugging in QtCreator without problems. The program return a sigsegv in namedWindow("Edge map", 1);
I found this bug reported https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/changeset/5513 and i have de fix on my OpenCV version so i dont know how to proceed

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce your problem. It works for me. Maybe you had OpenCV installed from deb package earlier and it hasn't been fully removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Ubuntu versions after 10.10 you'll run into this in more related applications, such as QtCreator. It is a security *feature* of Ubuntu that prevent the debugger to attach to processes not owned by him.

This is filed as a [bug #3509 against QtCreator](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-3509). To work around this issue, do this:

- temporary solution (won't survive a reboot):

  ```
   echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
  ```
- In a file `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf` (should already exist), change the value of `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope` to `0` and then reload the configuration: `sudo sysctl -p`.

I'm explicitly posting the temporary solution, as you probably don't want to keep this feature disabled on a regular machine for security reasons.